# Change text using a variable in InDesign javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, find, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to find all "#"s on the active page and change them to numbers, ie. 1, 2, 3 . . .

The code below is what I thought would work but it doesn't. Instead, it changes every "#" to a "0".

```
app.findTextPreferences = app.changeTextPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
app.findTextPreferences.findWhat = "#";

var finds = app.activeDocument.findText();
if (finds.length > 0) {
   for (var i = 0; i < finds.length; i++)  
   {  
      app.changeTextPreferences.changeTo = "no: " + i;
      app.activeDocument.changeText();
   }  
   else
   {
      alert("Nothing has been found");
   }
}
```

Comment: This line "var finds = app.activeDocument.findText();" is not accepting the "#" character .. is it correct?

Comment: @Zafta it does when i run it, then finds every "#" and changes them to 0.

Comment: can you please console variable "i" inside the loop

Comment: i'm sorry I don't know how to do that..

Comment: Inside you for loop, write this console.log(i);

Comment: it says "console is undefined", i'm sorry i'm really new..

Comment: I think the problem is changeText() changes everything at once, there is nothing left to change to 1... 2... while the loop works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ali haydar stated, changeText will apply globally and will break the former findText texts references. What you need is to use the contents property in your loop.

```
app.findTextPreferences = app.changeTextPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
app.findTextPreferences.findWhat = "#";

var finds = app.activeDocument.findText();
if (finds.length > 0) 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < finds.length; i++)  
    {  
      finds[i].contents = "no: " + String(i);
    }  
}
else
{
alert("Nothing has been found");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! How is the best approach to limit this find/change only on the current page?

Comment: Shouldn't be there a "{" between the first "if" and "for"?

Comment: Indeed. I just copy/pasted your code without closer look. It's always a good move to add curly braces and semi-colons even if possibly optional.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can even get rid of the if condition:

```
app.findTextPreferences = app.changeTextPreferences = null;
app.findTextPreferences.findWhat = "#";

var finds = app.activeDocument.findText();
var n = finds.length;
var nStart = n;
while (n-- ) finds[n].contents = "no: " + String(n+1);
alert(nStart? nStart+" replacements made…" : "Nothing has been found");
```

Comment: Thank you, this works too, and certainly looks better. But it says "-1 replacements made" after the changes, and when I hit ctrl+z, I see the replacements was made in reverse order, is it normal?

Comment: any comment on how to make this work only on the current page :)

Answer (score 0):

To consider page 1 only…

```
var main = function(){
    var doc = app.properties.activeDocument,
     finds,n;

    app.findTextPreferences = app.changeTextPreferences = null;
    app.findTextPreferences.findWhat = "#";

    if ( !doc ) return;
    finds = doc.findText();
    n = finds.length;

    while (n-- ) {
        finds[n].parentTextFrames.length
        && finds[n].parentTextFrames[0].isValid
        && finds[n].parentTextFrames[0].parentPage.id==doc.pages[0].id
        && finds[n].contents = "no: " + String(n+1);
    }

};

main();
```

Comment: thank you, i got an error "doc not defined"; if I define it like this `var doc = app.activeDocument` works on every page not just page 1

Comment: That doesn't make sense. I just edited snippet so it includes all necessary code. Did you leave your changeText call ?

Comment: can you make it count only when it changes, not every time it finds?